# Executing a function in PostgreSQL produces an error it does not exist, but it does exist

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

When I am trying to call a DB function to get the count in Spring, it will complain:

> function xyz.get_search_count_f(integer, character varying, character
> varying, bytea, bytea ) does not exist

In my service layer, I am calling it:

```java
Integer totalElements = ruleRepository.getRuleSearchCount(projectId, folderName, "%", null, null);
```

In the Repository, I am calling it:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * from xyz.get_search_count_f(:projectId, :folderName, :name, :ewoName, :type", nativeQuery = true)
Integer getRuleSearchCount( @Param("projectId") Integer projectId, @Param("folderName") String folderName,
                            @Param("name") String name, @Param("ewoName") String ewoName,
                            @Param("type") String type
                            )
```

For some reason, calling it from Spring does not work.

When I run the query directly from DBeaver, then it works.

The query:

```sql
select xyz.get_search_count_f(124567, 'FOLDERA', '%', null,null)
```

Why in Spring it could not find the database function in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What is the signature of the function? I suspect that is the issue that the types don't match (you are passing `null` and `null` as the last arguments which translate to `bytea` with your Spring data query method, if those don't match (i suspect it is a varchar) it won't find it. So does it match the signature or not. Also does the user have access and is it in the proper db, schema, etc.

Comment: You are right. Spring somehow transfer my null values to bytea. I just convert the null values to empty string "" , now it works!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that Spring will automatically transfer my null values to bytea.
For example, when I try to call the getRuleSearch method,

```
Integer totalElements = ruleRepository.getRuleSearchCount(projectId, folderName, "%", null, null);
```

the last two parameters for the db function are supposed to accept 2 VARCHAR which are String types in Java.

Since Spring converts the null vales to bytea instead of passing them as String.
It had trouble locating the db function.

Therefore, the way I fixed this issue is to
convert the null values to empty string "" , then it would be able to find the db function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).